# Unbiased estimators of bivariate gaussian means

Tags: normal-distribution, unbiased-estimator, bivariate

What are the best unbiased estimators of bivariate gaussian means given covariance matrix?  Is there any such estimator that makes explicit use of the covariance matrix, and which is superior by any criteria to the standard estimator of the means?

if the covariance matrix is unknown, the best we can do to estimate $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ is to let

$\hat{\mu}_1 = \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i,1} /N$ and  $\hat{\mu}_2 = \sum_{i=1}^N X_{i,2} /N$ right?

what if the covariance matrix is known? can it be useful in any way?

\begin{align}
   \Sigma&=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
    \sigma_1^2 & \sigma_{12} \\
    \sigma_{12}& \sigma_2^2
    \end{array}\right)  = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 
    \sigma_1^2 & \rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2} \\
    \rho \sigma_{1} \sigma_{2}& \sigma_2^2
    \end{array}\right) 
\end{align}

Comment: When you remove the restriction to *unbiased* estimators and move up to three or more dimensions, you indeed can exploit knowledge of the covariance: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stein%27s_example.

Comment: thanks! what if we keep the restriction? is there any proof that the covariance is useless?

Comment: in addition, Stein example only works for 3 or more dimensions -- what about 2 dimensions?

Comment: The [Gauss-Markov Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Markov_theorem#Generalized_least_squares_estimator) (in the case of Generalized Least Squares) implies a negative result in *all* dimensions when you confine your estimator to the class of linear unbiased ones.